# Can't push the data to array in Firestore + React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I want to collect the UIDs to the Array fields in Firestore. Successfully fetched each user data, however, I can't list.

> contactArray: {"0": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "1": "yyyyyyyyyyyy"}

User data can be retrieved, but the problem cannot be displayed as a list. I could push it, but it disappears for some reason.

The warning:

> Expected to return a value in arrow function

**useEffect**

```
const [contactList, setContactList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUserUid) {
    firestore.doc(`users/${currentUserUid}`).get().then(userSnapshot => {
      const { contactUidList } = userSnapshot.data()
      return contactUidList
    })
      .then((contactUidList) => {
        contactUidList.map((contactUid) => {
          firestore.doc(`users/${contactUid}`)
            .onSnapshot(userQuerySnapshot => {
              contactList.push(userQuerySnapshot.data())
              setContactList(contactList)
            })
        })
      })
  }
}, [currentUserUid, contactList])
```

**View**

```
  return (
    <ul>
      {contactList.map((contact, idx) => {
          return(<p>{contact.name}</p>)
       ))
  )
```

Comment: To get rid of that warning, you'll either want to remove the `=>` in `.then((contactUidList) => {` or return something (it doesn't really matter what) at the end of that callback.

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and most cloud APIs) asynchronously. For that reason you'll need to keep `contactList` in the state, and update it there. When you do that, React knows to update the UI when the results come back from the database (or are updated).

So something like:

```
const [contactList, setContactList] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUserUid) {
    firestore.doc(`users/${currentUserUid}`).get().then(userSnapshot => {
      const { contactArray } = userSnapshot.data()
      return contactArray
    })
      .then((contactArray) => {
        contactUidList.map((contactUid) => {
          firestore.doc(`users/${contactUid}`)
            .onSnapshot(userQuerySnapshot => {
              contactList.push(userQuerySnapshot.data())
              setContactList(contactList)
            })
        })
      })
  }
}, [currentUserUid, contactList])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been successfully fetched `contactList`. But it has not been displayed yet...