# how to get realtime data with firestore and react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, function, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get an array of all users saved in my firestore, but it pulls only from the moment the app was started and not after creating a new user.

ClientsList.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  Text,  
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

import Background from '../components/Background'
import Header from '../components/Header'

import { listClients } from '../helpers/clientManager'

const ItemView = (item) => {
    return (  
      <Text  
        key={item.id}
        style={styles.itemStyle}  
        onPress={() => 
          getItem(item)
        }>  
        {item.id}  
        {' - '}  
        {item.nome.toUpperCase()}  
      </Text>  
    );  
};

const getItem = (item) => {  
    alert(
        `Cliente: ${item.nome}\n` +
        `Cadastro: ${item.cadastro}\n` +
        `Entrega: ${item.entrega}\n` +
        `ID: ${item.id}\n` +
        `Produtos: \n\n${item.produtos.map(p => `Nome: ${p.title} \nQuantia: ${p.amount} \nValor: R$ ${p.value} \n--------------`).join("\n")}`
    );  
};

export default function ClientsList({ navigation }) {

  (async function () {
    data = await listClients()
    
    return data
  })()

  return (
    <Background>
        <Header>Lista de todos os clientes atuais.</Header>
        <ScrollView>
            {
                    data.map(ItemView)
            }
        </ScrollView>
    </Background>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
    container: {  
      paddingTop: 40,  
      backgroundColor: 'white',  
    },  
    itemStyle: {  
      backgroundColor: '#0066CC',  
      padding: 10,  
      marginVertical: 8,  
      marginHorizontal: 10,  
      color: 'white' 
    },  
  });
```

clientManager.js

```js
import { firebase } from './firebase'

const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('clientes')

export async function listClients(id) {
    let docsAll = await getMarkers()

    return docsAll
}

async function getMarkers() {
    const markers = [];
    await firebase.firestore().collection('clientes').get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        markers.push(doc.data());
      });
    });
    return markers;
  }
```

I need to know a method of having this information in real time, since I have no idea (or if I forgot something basic) how to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're calling `get()`, which [loads data only once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) - when the code executes.

If you want to continue to monitor the database for changes, you should [use a real-time listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) - with the `onSnapshot` method. This is typically done in a `useState` hook, so that you can [attach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) to the database when the component is added to the UI, and [detach the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) when the component is removed from the UI.

For examples of how to do this, have a look at these questions and their answers:

- [Which react hook to use with firestore onsnapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59944658/which-react-hook-to-use-with-firestore-onsnapshot/59959589#59959589)
- [React useState and Firebase onSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214878/react-usestate-and-firebase-onsnapshot/70218218#70218218)
- [Firebase listener with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977856/firebase-listener-with-react-hooks/60029676#60029676)
- [Can't push the data to array in Firestore + React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132847/cant-push-the-data-to-array-in-firestore-react-hooks/62135133#62135133)